# Sitecore DMS vs. Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, sitecore, traffic-measurement, sitecore-dms

I'd like to ask you about a reason to justify DMS usage against what GA offers. It's one of basic questions that arise when a customer is used to Google Analytics and we have to convince them to switch to DMS. 
What are the areas in which DMS is superior to GA when it comes to analytics?

Comment: Like your previous question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699668/sitecore-dms-profiles-solution-vs-other-scoring-systems] around a similar topic this is considered "not constructive" in SO.

Answer (score 2):

DMS is integrated directly into Sitecore and so offers to the you the chance to fully customize the content which is displayed to users and not just collect statistics like GA would.

Add to that things like customer profiling, personas, campaigns and goals, integration with Email Campaign Manager, integration with offline marketing efforts etc. Based on all these you can serve different content to your users to fully target a specific audience, 
imagine a completely different homepage carousel based on your previous browsing habits, or if you came through a particular QR code for example.

Have a read of the following article which lists all the features and why they may be important. http://www.awareweb.com/AwareBlog/4-30-12-DMSFeatures.aspx

This isn't a one size fits all. For some sites all this may be very important, but for others the Google Analytics may provide them with everything they need.

Since you are a developer I presume, if you haven't then you may want to take a look at DMS in action: http://launchsitecore.net/ and have a look through the JetStream demo site which is available through Sitecore Partner Network.

Comment: Agree with @jammykam . You should also check the series of blog posts discussing Sitecore and Google Analytics on Michael Casey blog: http://mikecaseycms.blogspot.com/2013/01/launch-sitecore-and-google-analytics.html

Comment: Thank you both - these are some points and good links.